# Failed upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I was upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04. I am new to Ubuntu. It went well until the end. It downloaded all the new packages. While installing. Towards the end I got the following errors.

```
Could not install "initscripts."
```

Then it gave the following message.

```
Upgrade will continue, but the initscripts packages may not be working state. 
Please submit a bug report.
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1.
```

It gave following additional errors.

```
Could not install "plymouth."
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1.
Could not install "cgmanager."
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1.
Could not install "rfupdown."
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1.
Couldn't install the upgrades.
The update has aborted. Your system should be in an unstable state. 
A recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a).
```

It showed version 16.04, but with only one option, shutdown. I did that. Then I had to install an earlier version of 14.04 through a factory image.

What do I do now?